# Delete Duplicates From CSV with 5M Rows

Tags: csv

What is the quickest way to delete duplicate entries from a CSV file with over 5 million rows and 1 column? I tried a few freeware programs but they keep crashing and excel only supports 1M Rows.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a high-level answer only (no code), because we don't have details of the file or anything else in the question to build off of... not even what language to use.

**Sort** first.
**Iterate** through the data second.
**Copy** good (unique) rows to *new file*.
**Replace** the original file with the copy when you're done.

You will easily know which rows are "good" because the data is sorted, so you only need to keep the value from the previous row to compare with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running on a Mac or Linux box (or something Unix-y), this bash command will do the trick:

```
sort < my_big_file.csv | uniq > deduped.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can use

```
$noDupes = @(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\original.csv') | Sort-Object -Unique 
$noDupes | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Temp\deduped.csv' -Force
```